# Connect to MongoDB running on docker having IP whitelist from AWS Lambda

Tags: mongodb, docker, networking, aws-lambda

I have a mongodb running on docker on an ec2 instance. The way it is setup, I use security rules to whitelist IPs that can access the 27017 port on the ec2 instance. I am trying to create a lambda function that can access the mongoDB, but lambda functions do not have a static ip, so it is not able to connect to MongoDB. What approach would solve this issue?

I was looking at AWS VPC and tried usinge the PrivateLink feature, but that did not seem to work. How do I enable the lambda function to be able to access the MongoDB database?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.